# Elasticsearch: Constructing mappings for Java Client

Tags: elasticsearch

In my `elasticsearch.yml` file am trying to implement some mapping where one field belonging to one type is indexed using a different analyzer to the rest.

At present the yaml file has the following structure:

```
index:
  bookshelf:
    types:
      book:
        mappings:
          title: {analyzer: customAnalyzer}
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      # set standard analyzer with no stop words as the default
      default:
        type: standard
        stopwords: _none_
      # set custom analyser to provide relative search results
      customAnalyzer:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: nGramTokenizer
        filter: [lowercase,stopWordsFilter,asciifolding]
    tokenizer:
      nGramTokenizer:
        type: nGram
        min_gram: 1
        max_gram: 2
    filter:
      nGramFilter:
        type: nGram
        min_gram: 1
        max_gram: 2
      stopWordsFilter:
        type: stop
        stopwords: _none_
```

This does not apply the custom analyzer to the title field, so I was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction for applying custom analyzers to individual fields?

Comment: Did you figure out why your customAnalyzer was not being applied to the title field? I can't sense out of the accepted answer

Comment: @BrianWebster no, I wasn't able to get it to work. I put it in a backlog with the intention of coming back to it. If you do succeed in implementing the custom analyzer then please add your solution to this question. Thanks

Comment: Will do. I'm still new in the process. However, I wonder if there is a possibility that it is being applied and it's just hard to detect? For example, I do not believe ES has a way to view tokens (the result of an analyzer being applied). Could you list the test case that you are using?

Comment: @BrianWebster There is an [analysis API](http://www.elasticsearch.or/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answered this in the ml:

If you are using Java you don't have to use an yml file. You can, but you don't have to.

If you are using Spring, you can have a look at the ES spring factory project:  https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch

If not, there is different ways of creating index and mappings in Java:

1. You can have a look here to see how I'm doing this by reading a json
   mapping file: 
   https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/pilato/spring/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAbstractClientFactoryBean.java#L616
2. You can also use XContent objects provided by ES to build your
   mappings in Java: 
   https://github.com/dadoonet/rssriver/blob/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/river/rss/RssRiverTest.java#L14
3. Using this object is described here:  https://github.com/dadoonet/rssriver/blob/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/river/rss/AbstractRssRiverTest.java#L98

Adding the mapping as follows:

```
node .client() .admin () .indices()
 .preparePutMapping ("yourindex" )
 .setType ( "yourtype" )
 .setSource ( mapping ())
 .execute() .actionGet ();
```

I hope this could help you

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer here as well David - I like to be able to up-vote helpful things :) I am still playing with this and trying to get it to work for me.