# configuring elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

I was exploring the documentation and Q&A regarding on how to configure an index in ES. At some point I get really confused. I found two different versions/ways (?) on how to do it, but I can't seem to find what the difference is.

(1) this one: [Elasticsearch: Constructing mappings for Java Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727690/elasticsearch-constructing-mappings-for-java-client) which seems to be one yml file that contains all the definitions for the index *bookshelf* (in the given example)

(2) a definition of a tweet: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/object-type/ (JSON)

to me, (1) seems to be more conclusive. but anyway, what confuses me is that (1) has *mappings* defined, and (2) has *properties* - what is the difference? what is the correct/better way of defining fields for types of an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both kinda the same really. 1. Is just being fed to a client which will eventually just output a JSON file that **looks like** 2.

The reason 2 looks odd to you is because its documenting/demonstrating a specific type of mapping, not telling you how to create index mappings.

If you're using an [elasticsearch client](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/clients/) then consult the documentation for how they want you to specify mappings, if you want to interface with elasticsearch using REST commands directly then [read this documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-create-index/), (read it anyway to understand how to construct mappings in general)

Comment: thanks for ur fast reply. m using Java API, and I'll try to generate a yml document just as (1) and feed this to generate the index. I like to have the whole definition in one place, not in the code